# Benefit of Generic Constructors

Tags: java, generics, polymorphism

What is the benefit of having generic constructor for a non-generic class?  Java spec permits the following:

```
class NonGeneric {
  <T> NonGeneric() { }
  ...
  NonGeneric ref = new <String> NonGeneric();
}
```

Can one come up with a realistic example of when it enhances the typesafety of the class?  How would it be better than using Generic in the first place.

I understand that Java designers wanted the constructors to be more consistent with methods.
Given that constructors can have side-effects, generic constructors can use generics to mutate some parameters whose references aren't retained, as in

```
<T> NonGeneric(T obj, List<T> list) {
  list.add(obj);
  // Don't hold a reference to list
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only use that I can think of would be if the constructor needed to use a generic object while it was running, but did not store that object once it was complete.

For example:

```
<T> NonGeneric(T[] blank, List<T> list) {
    // Sort that list
    T[] array = list.toArray(blank);
    Arrays.sort(array);

    // Pull out the values as strings
    this.list = new ArrayList<String>(array.length);
    for (T value : array) {
        this.list.add(value.toString());
    }
}
```

It is most likely just something that the language designers decided to do just in case somebody wanted it, since there was no reason to prevent people from doing it.

Comment: Yeah, it allows generic methods to be replace by constructors (but why would you want to?). I've never actually seen one in the wild. For my money, it's a complication that the language could have done without (as C# did later when it introduced its version of Java generics).

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I was thinking about the same a few times.

Hypothetically (there are xx reasons why it is not like this) it would be nice if Generic constructors could define formal generic type for the whole class (as generic class declaration does) ... That is to say, if defining Generic constructor would let you have generic fields in that class...

For instance if you wanted to avoid generalization :

```
EntityRequestCallback extends RequestCallback
```

but you wanted the RequestCallback to be generic `RequestCallback<E extends Entity>`, you couldn't do that because only two types of request PUT/POST use Entity. Only constructors for PUT/POST requests contains Entity parameter.

```
public class RequestCallback {

        /** GET/DELETE requests */
    public RequestCallback(String gttUrl, HttpMethod method,) {
        this.gttUrl = gttUrl;
                this.method = method;
    }

        /** PUT/POST requests */
    public RequestCallback(String gttUrl, HttpMethod method, Entity entity) {
        this.gttUrl = gttUrl;
                this.method = method;
        this.entity = entity;
    }
}
```

But the class cannot be generic because you would be creating RequestCallback for a Request that doesn't have an Entity, which would mean you would instantiate

```
new RequestCallback();  //without specifying generic parameter - worse than nothing
```

So that the only possible way here is generalization :

```
EntityRequestCallback<E extends Entry> extends RequestCallback
```

So that you can have generic fields :

```
public E entity;
```

In this particular example, the generalization is the right choice anyway, but there are cases where generalization wouldn't be.