# Java generic class token

Tags: java, android, generics, reflection

I want to encapsulate requests to my android service because the service has the information to generate the appropriate commands. However I would like to constrain class tokens sent to the service extended from ICommand, so that I dont allow sending of requests with invalide tokens. This will explain more:

```
public class ServiceRequestArgs implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7484807396752170166L;

    private Class m_token; 
    //warning: references to generic type Class<T> should be parameterized
    private IFileUploadListener m_listener;

    public <T extends ICommand> ServiceRequestArgs(
        Class<T> cmdClass, IFileUploadListener listener)
    {
        m_token = cmdClass;
        m_listener = listener;
    }

    public Class getClassToken() //warning: references to generic...
    {
        return m_token;
    }

    public IFileUploadListener getListener()
    {
        return m_listener;
    }
}

//use ->
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
intent.putExtra("svc_command", 
    new ServiceRequestArgs(GetListCommand.class, m_listener);
bindService(intent, m_serviceConnection, 0);
```

I understand C# generic constraints, but I am not sure how I should be using this in Java.

**Edit**
Heres what I came up with:

```
public class ServiceRequestArgs<T extends ICommand> {

    private ServiceRequestArgs(Class<T> token, IFileUploadListener listener);

    public Class<T> getClassToken(); //...
    public IFileUploadListener getListener(); //...

    //to make it easier to call. sorry, cant remember where I found this.
    public <C extends ICommand> ServiceRequestArgs<C> create(
        Class<C> token, IFileUploadListener listener)
    {
        return new ServiceRequestArgs<C>(token, listener);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would implement this as a generic class, rather than trying to implement a generic constructor:

```
public class ServiceRequestArgs<T extends ICommand> {

    private Class<T> m_token;
    private ICommand m_listener;

    public ServiceRequestArgs(Class<T> cmdClass, ICommand listener)
    {
        m_token = cmdClass;
        m_listener = listener;
    }

    public Class<T> getClassToken()
    {
        return m_token;
    }

    public IFileUploadListener getListener()
    {
        return m_listener;
    }
}
```

This way, the generic type `T` (constraint and all) are usable throughout the class. Most of the time, generic constructors (for a non-generic class) [aren't the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300037/benefit-of-generic-constructors).

Comment: I was trying to see if I even needed to pass the token to the constructor if I have the type in the class parameter. so... ServiceRequestArgs<DoSomethingCommand> = new ServiceRequestArgs<DoSomethingCommand>(MyListener); however, T.class does not exist for seamingly obvious reasons.. but I could not find a reasonable alternative.

Comment: Is there a question in your comment? You cannot reference the class of the generic type parameter `T` as `T.class`, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: No, I feel that its redundandt to pass the generic argument and then the parameter DoSomethingCommand.class to the constructor, if I already pass the type can I use reflection to get the .class token or something?

Comment: I still needed to pass the class (ok, I coulda passed an identifier to determine what to construct on the other side but I am stubborn). What I ended up doing was making a static create method.

Answer (score 1):

You want to make the class generic first.  Constructors shouldn't have their own generic parameters.

So

```
public class ServiceRequestArgs<T extends ICommand> implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7484807396752170166L;

    private Class<T> m_token; 
    //warning: references to generic type Class<T> should be parameterized
    private IFileUploadListener m_listener;

    public ServiceRequestArgs(
        Class<T> cmdClass, IFileUploadListener listener)
    {
        m_token = cmdClass;
        m_listener = listener;
    }

    public Class<T> getClassToken() //warning: references to generic...
    {
        return m_token;
    }

    public IFileUploadListener getListener()
    {
        return m_listener;
    }
}
```